# Change image if any checkbox on the page was checked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of checkboxes with different IDs on the page.

I want to change picture everytime when any checkbox was checked or unchecked...

Please, tell me how to do that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic code is shown below. Bind a `onchange` event to each `input[type=checkbox]`.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    $('#imgid').attr('src', 'newimg.png');
})
```

Pure JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=inputs.length-1; i>=0; i--){ //Loop through each input element in the page
    var input = inputs[i];
    if(input.type == "checkbox"){
        input.onchange = function(){   //Bind `change` event handler
            document.getElementById("imgId").src = "newimg.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The previously shown code snippets have to be called when the document has loaded. Either by using `window.onload = function(){ /*Code here*/ }`, or by adding the code at the end of the document.

Comment: This assumes you're using jquery (or a compatible library like Zepto).

Comment: Wow! Very fast reply. Thank's Rob!

Comment: @Derek I first typed the short code, then I started writing the new code. In under two minutes :)

Comment: @RobW - cool. Just pointing it out in case the OP tried it and saw it not work.

Comment: Rob, your code is working great. I'am trying to extend it like this:
input.onchange = function(){   //Bind `change` event handler
       if (input.checked == true)
        document.getElementById("aybi").src = "aybi_hug.png";
       else if (input.checked == false) document.getElementById("aybi").src = "aybi_angry.png";
      }

But it's not working. Any advice?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Are you sure that the elements exist (IDs are case-sensitive)?

Comment: Yes, id exits. My picture - is a mascot. The idea is to change his emotion: when any checkbox was checked src="aybi_hug.png", if any checkbox was unchecked src=""aybi_angy.png"

Comment: Can you post your code at http://jsfiddle.net, and place the link in the comments?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/OkAlex21/Ue2De/ - jsFiddle;
or you can try to check the checkbox here:
http://f1u.org/freeflight2/form.php

Comment: @Ok-Alex Inside the `onchange` event handler, you have to use `this` instead of `input`.

Comment: Thank's Rob! My mascot is alive now :)